# Determine number of times the DOM was manipulated/appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Is there a way to count the amount of times that the DOM has been appended to?

Comment: by *"manipulated"*, what actions does that include? and for what particular reason?

Comment: i mean each time an .append() or an .html() adds/changes something in the DOM, sorry that i wasn't very clear, we are using backbone and I think we have a memory leak due to it, i am not 100% tho

Comment: if you are just profiling/testing the page, why not just use a debugger like firebug or dragonfly. that way, you see what the scripts are doing, and when it does these things. unless you have time extending all DOM manipulation methods of the libraries you use. also, manipulation isn't limited to just appending, it's also moving around elements, removing them, adding text, moving around boxes, event attatchments.. that's a lot.

Comment: If it's just for debug, you can use the mutation events. probably the `DOMNodeInserted` event is a good candidate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're stricly after `.append()`, you can just patch it, like:

```
var _origAppend = $.fn.append;
$.appendCount = 0;

$.fn.append = function() {
    $.appendCount++;
    return _origAppend.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Now, you could just access `$.appendCount` at anytime to see how often it was called. However, be aware that there are lots of functions which can manipulate the DOM. It might be a more clever idea, to patch `jQuery.fn.domManip` instead. That method is called internally basically at any dom manipulation (like you might have suspected because of the name)

Comment: **+1** You have a typo in the first line `.appends()` => `.append()`. And you forgot the comma in the last line.. `_origAppend.apply(this arguments);` => `_origAppend.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: See his [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730555/determine-number-of-times-the-dom-was-manipulated-appended/9730578#comment12373413_9730555) It's not just `.append()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `mutation events`.
Be aware they have a huge performance impact!

> The mutation event module is designed to allow notification of any changes to the structure of a document, including attr and text modifications. It may be noted that none of the mutation events listed are designated as cancelable. This stems from the fact that it is very difficult to make use of existing DOM interfaces which cause document modifications if any change to the document might or might not take place due to cancelation of the related event. Although this is still a desired capability, it was decided that it would be better left until the addition of transactions into the DOM.

[Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents)